# Manage different date formats in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, parsing

I'm trying to figure out how best to handle different date formats that I might have as input.
The specific case is about the dates dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy.

At the time I try to convert the date as below:

firstDate = CDate("10/22/1988")

It obviously returns an error, how can I handle both cases in a generic way?

Comment: Have you considered what to do with e.g. 3/5/1988?

Comment: How are these dates "inputed", i.e. what control do you use for it? Use the proper control (DateTimePicker) for user input and retrieve the date from it by its `.Value` property, which returns a `DateTime` variable.

Comment: The general idea is that, for input, you use a tool that only handles DateTime values. You should specify what UI Platform you're using. If it's a Console app, accept input formats from, e.g., `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` or force a specific format (notify the users) or the InvariantCulture formats.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Date.TryParseExact` with the allowed format patterns:

```
Dim patterns As String() = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy"}
Dim dt As Date
Dim valid = Date.TryParseExact(str, patterns, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
```

Here a full working demo:

```
Sub Main
    Dim inputs As String() = {"10/22/1988", "22/10/1988"}
    Dim patterns As String() = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy"}
    
    For Each str As String In inputs
       Dim dt As Date
       Dim valid = Date.TryParseExact(str, patterns, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
       Console.WriteLine($"Valid: {valid} Date-Value: {dt}")
    Next
End Sub
```

Output(i'm in germany):

```
Valid: True Date-Value: 22.10.1988 00:00:00
Valid: True Date-Value: 22.10.1988 00:00:00
```

In case of input like "3/5/1988" you should also allow:

```
"M/d/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy"
```

In this case the order is also the priority, so if both could work, the first wins.